# How to Change button back color in c#

Tags: c#, background-color

I have many Buttons in DataGrid

I want to set
Button's color become Green and the Button.Text become white ( not for all, only for 1 button) in the basis of my if condition 
I alredy used ITextSharp for creating PDF generation,i commented the iTextSharp header files i get the result but i must need iTextSharp in my code this time bellowing error is occured.

"Cannot implicitly convert type  iTextSharp.text.Color  to System.Drawing.Color"

This is my iTextSharp header file

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
```

This is the code

```
            if (dsRecAdj.Tables[2].Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    Button btn = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnSalvage");
                    btn.ForeColor = Color.Red;

                }
```

Some Body please help me

Comment: You get that because they are different types. If the values are the same casting may be an option for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referencing the `Color` type in the iTextSharp.text namespace.  Try specifying the namespace explicitly:

```
btn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Comment: I used Your code but i get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: Then `btn` is probably `null`.  Check the `FindControl` call above.

Comment: Yes the FindControl value is null, i take a single grid view  FindControl value that is fine .In this case its a inner grid view. I am using RowDataBound Event of Parent GridView, to Binding Child GridView. My Problem is that, how to get Child GridView's Button findcontrol value in Parent gridViews RowDataBound Event. @Steve Czetty if anyone knows it,please help me solve this problem.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Button.BackColor property

Example :

```
btn.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

***Correction :*** OP's question title is misleading and the above is based on that
So the answer for the explanation in body of the question will be same as what OP have given

`btn.ForeColor = Color.Red;`//don't see the reason why this should not work

Comment: they want to change the forecolor, but type differing types is the problem

Comment: I understand the -1 my answer is based on OP question title, but op's question is nothing like his title and misleading

Comment: @HatSoft: I agree, +1, maybe edit your answer to include both

Comment: I didn't -1 you, but you're right the title and the details don't match

Comment: Cheers for supporting me guy's

Answer (score 1):

To change the BackColor use:

```
Button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

To change the ForeColor use:

```
Button1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

You can use both of them for the MouseMove event.

To reset both of them use the MouseLeave event with this code:

```
Buttton1.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace;
Button1.ForeColor = default(Color);
Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```